# Echoing options from column in mySQL (option/select)

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I've been working with this for almost an 3 hours now. It just seems unfixable. I've tried millions of options but just won't work.

So I want to echo from column title in table news so they apear like options in option select.
THis is how it looks now:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<?php
  global $mysqli;
  mysqli_connect($mysqli,'localhost', 'root', '');
  mysqli_select_db ($mysqli,"filip12356");

  $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM news";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

  echo "<select name='title_name'>";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['title'] . "'>" . $row['title'] . "</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you seem to be using mysqli_ everywhere except here...

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Should be..

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Comment: the mysql type would not make a difference in this case. this is an encoding issue.

Comment: Gotta be more specific when you say 'not working'.  Whats not working.  What errors do you receive.  Is it echoing the list, without the title but the options are empty, etc etc

Comment: Have you tested database connections with the setup you have going.  Like do other queries work fine?  Is it the query thats not working?  Or the connection?  etc etc

Comment: Col : http://pokit.org/get/?04ea5eeef80989609bfb2341bd8a6329.jpg 
THere is no errors, it just looks like this: http://pokit.org/get/?aa3f751c797e3d12560e60fb558321bb.jpg

I am creating CRUD in the admin panel so I want this for update, when someone chooses title of article, he is going to update that one.

P.s. I did test database con. everythings working fine

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure that all files are UTF-8 encoded without BOM. It seems that the server is misunderstanding the php as text.

Comment: Any idea how to change it?

Comment: It will depend on your editor. I use Notepad2 which allows a default for file encoding.